# Deleting from python heapq in O(logn)

Tags: python

I have a heap (python, heapq module) like this -

```
>>> h = []
>>> heappush(h, (5, 'write code'))
>>> heappush(h, (7, 'release product'))
>>> heappush(h, (1, 'write spec'))
>>> heappush(h, (3, 'create tests'))
```

How do I remove the tuple with item value as "create tests" in O(logn) and preserve the heap property?

This is what I could come up with (not O(logn))

```
for i in range(len(h)):
   if h[i][1] == "create tests":
      h[i], h[-1] = h[-1], h[i]
      popped = h.pop()
      heapq.heapify(h)
      break
```

Comment: Is there a reason you're using `heapq` for this? It's only really useful if you need to pop them off in order of priority (1, 3, 5, 7 in your example). If you need to do a lookup for a specific item your better off using a structure like a `dict` where you can look up keys in `O(1)` time.

Comment: I'm using a heap because I need to extract the min at each point. It also requires me to delete an entry, based on its key every now and then.

Comment: [The notes](http://docs.python.org/2/library/heapq.html#priority-queue-implementation-notes) tell you how to delete items. "every now and then" sounds like you don't have to care about speed anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid there's no such method with heapq only. Since searching an element from a heap requires `O(n)`.

But you can use it together with something like `dict`, which gives `O(1)` time for searching an entry.

**UPDATED:**

> I tried using a dict for bookkeeping, but how can I get the index of "create test" when it  was inserted? – Prakhar 3 hours ago

A naive approach would be:

```
# remember to update this hdict when updating the heap.
hdict = { h[i][1]: i for i in range(len(h)) }
```

Then you can just obtain index of a given string by accessing this `hdict` instead of your `O(n)` linear search.

Comment: I tried using a dict for bookkeeping, but how can I get the index of "create test" when it was inserted?

Answer (score 21):

If you do need to take an item out of the `heap` but want to preserve the `heap` you could do it lazily and discard it when the item comes out naturally, rather than searching through the list for it.

If you store items you want to remove in a blacklist `set`, then each time you `heapq.heappop` check if that item is in the `set`. If it exists discard it and `heappop` again until you get something that's not blacklisted, or the `heap` is empty

Comment: Or mark the item by setting its description to "*deleted*" or some other unique value.  Then examine the item when you pull it from the queue.

Comment: This is a brilliant idea.
And next answer with counting_dict solved the corner case - duplicated values.

Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

A blacklist set would be problematic if multiple deleted elements have the same value. Instead implement `heap_remove` using a tombstone-counting-dict:

```
def heap_remove(heap, value):
  tombstones[value] = tombstones.get(value, 0) + 1
  while len(heap) and heap[0] in tombstones and tombstones[heap[0]]:
      heappop(heap)
```

As expected, you have amortized O(1) removal time and the `top` of your heap is always accurate as long as you are not `popping` from the heap elsewhere.

Consider this list of numbers, which are first all pushed into the heap and then "removed" (not popped) in the same order:

> [3, 3, 2, 7, 1, 4, 2]

Inserts work as expected:

```
After inserting 3 into heap, top = 3
After inserting 3 into heap, top = 3
After inserting 2 into heap, top = 2
After inserting 7 into heap, top = 2
After inserting 1 into heap, top = 1
After inserting 4 into heap, top = 1
After inserting 2 into heap, top = 1
```

But removals are done by incrementing the object's tombstone. If the top of the heap has it's tombstone set, then remove the object and decrement the tombstone counter.

```
Called remove( 3 )
  Marking 3 for deletion
Called remove( 3 )
  Marking 3 for deletion
Called remove( 2 )
  Marking 2 for deletion
Called remove( 7 )
  Marking 7 for deletion
Called remove( 1 )
  Marking 1 for deletion
  Deleting top 1
    Updated heap is: [2, 2, 3, 7, 3, 4]
  Deleting top 1
    Updated heap is: [2, 3, 3, 7, 4]
Called remove( 4 )
  Marking 4 for deletion
Called remove( 2 )
  Marking 2 for deletion
  Deleting top 2
    Updated heap is: [3, 3, 4, 7]
  Deleting top 3
    Updated heap is: [3, 7, 4]
  Deleting top 3
    Updated heap is: [4, 7]
  Deleting top 4
    Updated heap is: [7]
  Deleting top 7
    Updated heap is: []
```

Notice that when the second `heap_remove(3)` is called @GP89's solution breaks down as `3` was already in the tombstone set.

You can explore this example [here](https://repl.it/J12n/0).

Answer (score 3):

With above 2 ideas,
here is a complete demo: I'll make it clean and concise soon.

```
from heapq import heappush, heappop

class Solution:

  def demo():

    deleted = {}
    h = [0]

    heappush(h, 789)
    heappush(h, 101)
    heappush(h, 101)

    self.remove(h, 101, deleted)

    max_val = self.peek(h, deleted)

  def remove(self, h, y, deleted):
    deleted[y] = deleted.get(y, 0) + 1
    while len(h) > 0 and h[0] == y and deleted[y] > 0:
        heappop(h)
        deleted[y] -= 1

  def peek(self, h, deleted):
    while len(h) > 0 and deleted.get(h[0],0) > 0:
        deleted[h[0]] -= 1
        heappop(h)
    return h[0]
```

Answer (score 1):

In this approach, I'm basically keeping track of elements in a dictionary. So, whenever, I'm deleting it, the search process becomes O(1).

```
import heapq
import collections
import itertools

class RemoveHeap:
    def __init__(self):
        self.h = []
        self.track = collections.defaultdict(collections.deque)
        self.counter = itertools.count()

    def insert_item(self, val):
        count = next(self.counter)
        item = [val, count, 'active']
        self.track[val].append(item)
        heapq.heappush(self.h, item)

    def delete_item(self, val):
        if val in self.track:
            items = self.track[val]
            for item in items:
                if item[2] == 'active':
                    item[2] = 'deleted'
                    break

    def pop_item(self):
        while len(self.h) > 0:
            item = heapq.heappop(self.h)
            item_track = self.track[item[0]]
            item_track.popleft()
            if len(item_track) == 0:
                del self.track[item[0]]
            else:
                self.track[item[0]] = item_track
            if item[2] == 'active':
                return item[0]

    def peek_item(self):
        item = self.h[0]
        if item[2] == 'deleted':
            x = self.pop_item()
            self.insert_item(x)
            return x
        return item[0]
```